# python program as "sit and wait listener"

Tags: python, multithreading, inter-process-communicat

Okay people this is an easy one. I want my python program to sit and listen for another process to tell it what to do.

```
ProcessA.c starts -> 
    ProcessA starts python listener program -> 
    ProcessA asks it for stuff from time to time
```

I can make my python program sit and wait for input, but after that I'm stuck. Do I need to use sockets?

What can I use to talk to my running python program from another program?

Comment: This seems to answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/a/4950283/665400

Comment: Since this is a self-admitted duplicate, you should probably delete this question.

Comment: I wasn't able to locate that via Google easily though so I think it's still valuable to have that question reworded here for future lost pythonians.